# How to write integration tests?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, continuous-integration, integration-testing

My team develops a Web API 2 application using Entity framework 6 ORM.

Our application acts as an email, and it's main purpose and action is to send a letter from one client to another.

Since it's the application's main purpose, we'd all like to have an integration test that will assure us that a letter is sent correctly. That is because we don't want to accidentally insert code that will break that.

When sending a letter the main actions that happen and that we'd like to test are-

- A letter is received through **HTTP Post** method and is validated on server
- The letter is saved to the **Database**.
- The letter is serialized.
- The serialized letter is sent to the specified destinations through an **external** module.
- The letter is deserialized on reciever side.
- The letter is added to recieved client's database.

I'm asking this because I'm clueless about how to approach this, yet I really want that sort of test which I can rely on.

How should a test for this be set? Where do I start? How to achieve an actual letter sending through a test and make sure it works?

It doesn't have to be an end to end test.

Thanks

Edit:

I don't mind tests to take long time, they can be run at night, but I want them to verify as much as possible that the application main parts are working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up multiple, non-actual code tests to verify your logic:

1. Reception of the letter, and it's logic
2. Verify that the save method to the database is invoked only when it should
3. Verify the serialization/deserialization bits of code
4. Verify that the destination picker module is working correctly.

Once you have these "non-invoking" tests, you know that all the bits of your system are working correctly individually. You can then set up a unit-test with some kind of marking (i.e. TestCategory("SUPERSLOW")) and then have that run manually against a mocked set of recipients for verification during integration test runs, NOT as part of your CI.

Keywords here are:

- SOLID principles
- Separation of Concerns
- Mocking
- Continuous Integration
- Inversion of Control

Comment: We do we have unit tests for all application parts, we wanted a few tests to cover it all up together and make sure we don't ruin the sending

Comment: I don't mind this test to be super long and run at night, but I want to it to verify as much as possible that everything works, not just that correct methods are called.

Comment: True, and I'm not saying that you shouldn't run an integration test, however, it should not be part of your continuous integration, but something that you either run manually, or at best, nightly, otherwise, it'll ruin your developer experience. The main concern here is speed of execution. If tests start to run slow, people stop writing them.

Comment: Yes, I don't mind if it isn't a part of the CI and runs at night, but how do I write such a test?

Comment: You tag it as "slow" or something, and then exclude all tests in that category during daytime, in your nightly build, you can allow all tests to execute.